# Relation between $\dim V$ and $\dim V^{\star}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an arbitary vector space $V$, suppose the dual space $V^{\star}$ is finite-dimensional, can we conclude that $V$ is also finite-dimensional?

Generally, is there an inequality between $\dim V$ and $\dim V^{\star}$?

Comment: see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i)

Comment: A vector space canonically injects into its double dual, and if $V^\ast$ is finite-dimensional, then $V^{\ast \ast}$ has the same dimension; so to inject into $V^{\ast \ast}$, $V$ must be finite dimensional, and thus $\dim V = \dim V^\ast$. As to your second, $\dim V \leq \dim V^\ast$ (consider the dual of your basis...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ over $K$, every map $B\to K$ extends uniquely to a linear map $V\to K$, i.e., to an element of $V^*$. Since $K$ contains distinct elements $0,1$, for every $v\in B$ one has the map $B\to K$ that has value $1$ at $v$ and $0$ elsewhere (the characteristic function of $\{v\}\subseteq B$), and the elements of $V^*$ corresponding to such maps are obviously linearly independent. (Because the evaluation at $v$ of a linear combination returns the coefficient of $v$; this is just the usual construction of a dual basis in the finite dimensional case, but these elements do not span $V^*$ in the infinite dimensional case.) This easy argument shows that $\dim V\leq\dim V^*$ always holds, and in particular $\dim V^*<\infty$ implies $\dim V<\infty$.

Since in the finite dimensional case the dual basis is a basis, one then has equality. That in the infinite dimensional case one has strict inequality requires more effort, but [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/13372/19077) to the question Troy Woo linked to gives an elegant proof.